# Python variable when importing second file in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and am working to redo my groovy/PowerShell code in Python. I've hit a snag when trying to import from another python file.

I have a list of dictionaries in a second python file that I call with the code below

```
from testdict import Dev1
```

in this case I am only importing a single Dictionary called `Dev1`, but I have 15 dictionaries in that file. I need to be able to variablize that and I think I can do it one of 2 ways.

either import the entire file (would rather not but I can) and then only select the dictionary I need. However I hit a snag when I try to reference the specific dictionary.

```
import testdict
dictionary =  testdict.env -- angry
```

Or I can only import the single dictionary, but I hit a snag in the import statement

```
from testdict import env -- angry
```

Again, the code works without a variable for the dictionary, but I need to variablize it so my code works in more than one situation.

Below is the code I currently have, and all I'm looking to do is replace `Dev1` with a variable I can pass into the method.

The script is doing a find and replace on T-SQL files based on the dictionary selected.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    def main(inputfile, outputfile, env):
        from testdict import Dev1
        #import testdict
        print (env)
            

        with open(inputfile, 'r') as file :
            filedata = file.read()


        dictionary =  Dev1
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            filedata = filedata.replace(key, dictionary[key])

        # Write the file out again
        with open(outputfile, 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)

    main('DropandAddDBUsers.sql','DropandAddDBUsers2.sql', 'Dev1')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "angry"? Do you have a variable in `testdict` named `env` or not? If `env` is a variable that *contains* the name of the variable, you can use `getattr(testdict, env)`, but you should probably have a single dict of dicts in `testdict` instead.

Comment: Whenever you need to export/import/share a collection of things, use a list (if numerically indexed) or a dict (otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

In `testdict.py` put all your dictionaries in another dictionary. Then you can select an entry from that dictionary.

```
alldicts = {'dev1': Dev1, 'dev2': Dev2, ...}
```

Then in the main script:

```
from testdict import alldicts

dictionary = alldicts[env]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to a module's  top level attributes/functions/classes as keys using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

You can do something like this:

```
import testdict

Dev1  = getattr(testdict, 'Dev1')
```

or:

```
for data in ('Dev1', 'Dev2'):
   current_dict = getattr(testdict, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for both responses!! I went with the method from Sal as I can keep my dictionaries readable (from my limited knowledge it looks like I need to make each sub dictionary on a single line for Barmar's approach and I have 60+ values).

For any interested in the the final result here it is:

```
    def main(inputfile, outputfile,env):
        #from testdict import alldicts
        import testdict
        print (env)
        env1 = getattr(testdict, env)
        


        


        with open(inputfile, 'r') as file :
            filedata = file.read()


        dictionary =  env1
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            filedata = filedata.replace(key, dictionary[key])

        # Write the file out again
        with open(outputfile, 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)

    main('DropandAddDBUsers.sql','DropandAddDBUsers2.sql', 'Dev1')
```